# How to generate for UPDATE statement with IN operator substitute values?

Tags: python, sql

I have to update rows which match fields using IN operator using python ?

```
UPDATE <tablename> WHERE fields in (<multiple values separated by comma>)
```

How can I generate my query which are separated by comma ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make:

```
values = [1,2,3]

query = "UPDATE <tablename> WHERE fields in ("+",".join(values)+")"
```

Comment: Don't put values directly in the query; use SQL parameters instead. Always.

Comment: this will improve something?